# Copy form field data from one form to another on a separate website?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, tampermonkey

So I have to input information into a form on a certain website, we'll call it *websiteA*. I have to enter the same information on another website for the state, we'll call it *websiteB*.

I'm looking for a way to streamline the process and have the information from *websiteA* automatically placed into the matching form fields on *websiteB*. This is just for local use on my own computer.

I'm new to the process and have been reading about different ways to do this. I'm currently trying to do this in Tampermonkey as that seems like my best option from doing a bit of research.
So far, below is what I have. As an example I'm just using one form field that requires a name. The ID of the element is `name`.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Form Copier
// @namespace    http://localhost
// @match        https://websiteA.com
// @match        https://websiteB.com
// @grant        GM_getValue
// @grant        GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==

if(document.URL.indexOf("https://websiteA.com") >= 0){
window.open('https://websiteB.com'); //opens the destination website
document.getElementById("name").value = GM_setValue("name");
}

else if(document.URL.indexOf("https://websiteB.com") >= 0){
    document.getElementById("name").value = GM_getValue("name");
}
```

This is currently what I have and it's not working right at all. I've tried to look for better ways to get this done and haven't had any luck. If any of you could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. That's not quite how to use `GM_setValue()`.  See [the documentation for `GM_setValue`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue).
2. Those `@match` directives need an `/*` at the end. (Unless you really want the exact home page, and no others.)
3. In case either page uses javascript techniques, use `waitForKeyElements` (or similar) to handle timing issues.
4. To avoid misfires, probably best to have *websiteB* delete the stored value after it has used it.

Putting it all together, the script would be like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Form Copier, Cross-domain
// @match    https://Sender.com/*
// @match    https://Receiver.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_getValue
// @grant    GM_setValue
// @grant    GM_deleteValue
// @grant    GM_openInTab
// ==/UserScript==

//-- Wait for the element with the ID "name".
waitForKeyElements ("#name", setOrGetName, true);

function setOrGetName (jNode) {
    if (location.hostname == "Sender.com") {
        //-- Store the `name` value:
        GM_setValue ("nameVal", jNode.val() );

        GM_openInTab ("https://Receiver.com/");
    }
    else if (location.hostname == "Receiver.com") {
        var nameVal = GM_getValue ("nameVal");
        if (nameVal) {
            //-- Set the form value:
            jNode.val (nameVal);
            //-- Reset storage:
            GM_deleteValue ("nameVal");
        }
    }
}
```